# Geany IDE on Scientific Linux

Tags: linux, repository, geany, scientific-linux

I installed [Scientific Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_Linux) 7. I would like to install Geany. I tried `sudo yum install geany` (in root) and also rpm, but it didn't work.

What can I do? Do you have to install something before using yum and rpm?

I read there are repositories, but I don't get it.

Comment: As a note for subsequent questions you post here - please provide more details about what you did, what did not work, what you did not understand, etc. That helps others help you.

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

- http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/extra/dag/packages/geany/

Looks like it's in the repository `extra`. I'm not using Scientific Linux, however given their release notes here:

- http://ftp.scientificlinux.org/linux/scientific/7rolling/x86_64/release-notes/

looks like `yum install yum-conf-extras` should enable the repository. You can then `yum update` and `yum install geany`.